# MPMoviePlayerController add subview in fullscreen

Tags: objective-c, controls, mpmovieplayercontroller, addition, subview

I have tried this but it is not working, I am struggling with this for last 7 hours, please help me. I want to add custom buttons to full screen view of MPMoviePlayer.

Code:

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        CustomControlsViewController *overlay = (CustomControlsViewController*)[mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Custom Controls"];

        [moviePlayerController.view addSubview:overlay.view];

        [moviePlayerController play];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1st of all, never ever add any subviews to `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view itself. Add them to its background view or its parent as a sibling.

This is discussed in the `MPMoviePlayerController` documentation:

> Consider a movie player view to be an opaque structure. You can add
>   your own custom subviews to layer content on top of the movie but you
>   must never modify any of its existing subviews. In addition to
>   layering content on top of a movie, you can provide custom background
>   content by adding subviews to the view in the backgroundView property.

2nd, when using proper fullscreen, the `MPMoviePlayerController` does not reuse its normal view but adds its content directly onto a `UIWindow` instance. Hence you got only the following option when using the "proper" fullscreen mode; find the current key-window and add your controls directly to it after having switched over to the fullscreen mode.

Something like this should do:

```
//are we in fullscreen-mode?
if (player.fullscreen)
{
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    if (!window)
    {
         window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    //we now got a proper window for use of our controls ... 
    //add them to the window instance!
}
```

As an alternative, simply don't use "proper" fullscreen but resize the MPMovieViewController's view to cover the entire screen - I call that "fake" fullscreen. One big advantage of this option is that you will be able to use/catch/cover the normal reorientation.

Comment: About your first point - the way I read it, it's ok to add subviews to the movieplayer view, but not modify any of the natively supplied views (eg. iterating through subviews and changing them).

Comment: You can safely add subviews to the player's view, as per the documentation "You can add subviews to the view in this property. You might do this in cases where you want to display custom playback controls or add other custom content that is relevant to your app." https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/view